# Communicate with another applications on the same machine

Tags: java, http, tomcat, ipc

I am working on a task, that requires me to communicate with another applications on the same machine.
the machine is a Windows 7 laptop.

There are in total 3 applications on the laptop. Their specifications are given below:

1. First application is coded in java and runs on a local Tomcat at port 6060
2. Second application is coded in java and runs on Tomcat at port 8080
3. Third application is coded in java and does not have Tomcat. It is a static web application.

Since application 1 and 2 are running on Tomcat, I have used HTTP to communicate with each other. However, since they are on the same machine, is there any other way for them to communicate with each other?

Application 2 needs to communicate with application 3. What is the best way for this communication.

Please let me know if you require any further information to answer my queries.

Comment: Have you heard about JMS ? im not sure if jms is necessary tho.

Comment: What web-server program is running for third application? That is a web application, so it must have some server app. Why second application can not communicate with that web server of third application?

Comment: The 3rd application is not hosted on any web server. It is a static application. We have a bunch of static HTML5 web pages, which use some Angular JS features.

Comment: We dont need JMS, as we are not sending multiple messages one after another asynchronously. When we communicate, we send 1 message at a time.